# SOQL injection checkmarx issue

Tags: apex

Can someone please help me resolve this issue. I am getting error as "SampleClass.cls 
Method sampleMethod at line 3 of classes\SampleClass.cls gets user input from the strVar element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated, and is eventually used in a database query in method sampleMethod at line 3 of classes\SampleClass.cls. This may enable an SOQL Injection attack. line no: 2, 5, 6" in checkmarx report.

```
public class SampleClass {
public String strVar {get; set;};
public void sampleMethod(){
if(strVar != null){     
    strVar = strVar.trim();
    List<String> varList = strVar.split(' ');   
    //logic
    String str1;
    String qString =  'select id, Description FROM Account';
    if(varList.size()==1){
        str1 = varList.get(0);
        queryStr+= ' and (Account.Name like \'%' + str1 + '%\')'; 
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: In providing a short example you have actually removed all the important context. I don't believe the code example you have would cause any warnings to be presented since there's no code flow that takes some user input through to building an SOQL query. Can I suggest you edit the question to add in the additional relevant code.

Comment: Edited the question. Getting issue at strVar = strVar.trim();
    List<String> varList = strVar.split(' ');

Comment: How is this different from https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279399/soql-injection-vulnerability-issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily resolved by either:

1. Using binding variables in your SOQL, though in your example the query is not shown as evaluated in the scope where the value is available or
2. Ensuring you use String.escapeSingleQuotes to ensure the inserted string doesn't permit injection of additional SOQL.

Take a look at this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/secdev_inject_prevent_soql_injection) for some more help.